# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished and load_missing_constant:NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I've spent the better part of two days on this, and things keep getting broken. It started when I added a couple environment variables to my .zshrc file, and then my installations of Rails stopped working, even after I removed the env variables. Is Rails getting confused about where to find the gems?

Ruby: 1.8.7
Rails: 2.3.16
Database adapter: mysql

**UPDATE** I think that I've solved it. It was just a case of missing gems that were required (not sure which ones exactly) that took care of both the Rail. Another issue was the required letter_opener gem, which required me to use specific_install (0.2.3, not 0.3.3, which looks like it uses a different Ruby). (What a nightmare!)

When I load the console, I immediately get this warning:

`~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:466:in 'load_missing_constant':NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie`

Even though the console loads, if I try to retrieve an Activerecord object e.g. User.last, I get an `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished` exception. Furthermore:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
=> {}
```

The database.yml file is fine because I pulled it straight from a repo (again, using mysql adapter):

```
development:
  host: localhost
  adapter: mysql
  username: [name]
  password: [pw]
  database: [db]
```

The directories in my PATH:

```
pp ENV["PATH"].split(":")
["~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin",
 "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@global/bin",
 "~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin",
 "~/.rvm/bin",
 "/usr/local/bin",
 "/usr/bin",
 "/bin",
 "/usr/sbin",
 "/sbin"]

mysql (2.9.1)
    Author: TOMITA Masahiro
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/mysql-win
    Homepage: http://github.com/luislavena/mysql-gem
    Installed at: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head  


rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-1.8.7-head (found in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head)
=> (default)
   global
```

**EDIT 1:** And my installed gems:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (2.3.16, 2.3.15)
actionpack (4.0.4, 3.0.0, 2.3.16, 2.3.15)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (2.3.16, 2.3.15)
activeresource (2.3.16, 2.3.15)
activesupport (4.0.4, 3.0.0, 2.3.16, 2.3.15)
addressable (2.3.6)
annotate (2.5.0)
awesome_print (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.1.4, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.15.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
childprocess (0.5.3)
chronic (0.10.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
contacts (1.2.4)
curb (0.8.6)
daemons (1.0.10)
delayed_job (2.0.8)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
dirty-memoize (0.0.4)
distribution (0.7.0)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
execjs (1.4.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
extendmatrix (0.3.1)
ezcrypto (0.7.2)
facter (2.1.0 universal-darwin)
faraday (0.9.1)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.9.18, 1.9.3)
gbarcode (0.98.16)
gdata (1.1.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
gpgme (2.0.2)
highline (1.6.15)
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11)
hpricot (0.8.6)
httparty (0.11.0)
httpclient (2.8.3, 2.4.0)
httpi (2.2.4)
i18n (0.8.6, 0.6.11, 0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
jwt (1.0.0)
launchy (2.4.3)
letter_opener (1.0.0)
libwebsocket (0.1.8)
linecache (0.46)
lockfile (2.1.3)
macaddr (1.7.1)
mail (2.6.1)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (1.18)
mini_magick (3.8.1)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
minimization (0.2.1)
minitest (5.10.3, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.10.1)
multi_xml (0.6.0, 0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mysql (2.9.1)
newrelic_rpm (3.14.2.312)
nokogiri (1.5.5)
parallel (1.1.2)
pony (1.10)
powder (0.2.1)
PriorityQueue (0.1.2)
rack (1.5.5, 1.2.8, 1.1.6)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.5.7)
rails (2.3.16, 2.3.15)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (10.1.1)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (4.2.0)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rghost (0.9.4)
rghost_barcode (0.9)
rmagick (2.13.2)
rspec (1.3.0)
ruby-saml (0.9)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
soap4r (1.5.8)
subexec (0.2.3)
systemu (2.6.5)
text-table (1.2.4)
thor (0.19.4, 0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tunnelss (0.1.1)
tzinfo (1.2.3, 0.3.53)
uuid (2.3.8)
uuidtools (2.1.5)
websocket (1.2.4)
whenever (0.9.2)
xml-simple (1.1.5)
```

Comment: *"I added a couple environment variables to my .zshrc file, and then my installations of Rails stopped working"* -- What did you add?

Comment: And I assume this is a legacy rails app, so you are unfortunately forced to use the *very* out-of-date ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.16

Comment: @TomLord Nothing fancy for my .zshrc file; I exported a MySQL username variable and a MySQL hostname variable. And yes, this is a legacy app.